# git command "merge-file" missing from git reference page

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm currently studying git by following the book "git progit".

In the book, the author mentioned a command called "merge-file".

I was looking at the [git reference page](https://git-scm.com/docs) and couldn't find the command, but a google search did show that the reference page for [merge-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) exists.

So I was just wondering, shouldn't the reference page contain all git commands? If `merge-file` command is missing from the reference page, what other commands are missing as well?

Comment: All git commands are listed on this page: https://git-scm.com/docs/git (which is the main manual page of git, accessible on the command line via `man git`)

Comment: @Leon thanks for pointing me to the link! For a brief moment, I was worried that the reference is incomplete. Really appreciate you helping out!